# How to config multiple monitor with optimus?

Tags: 12.04, xorg, nvidia-optimus, projector

I have an Acer Aspire 8951G running 12.04 Pangolin with bumblebee working beautifully.

My problem is that when I connect either the VGA port or the HDMI to my projector there is no way I can see to properly set up the resolutions or colours. The default basic display driver sees the projector correctly, but messes up colours and resolutions (on hdmi) and resolutions on VGA. (Its a 1280 X 720 projector)

Am I missing some sort of Xorg configuration? nvidia-xconfig does not seem to exist and running 
optirun nvidia-settings -c :8
opens the settings, but of course only for the one display.
I just want a way to set a default config for my projector via VGA or preferably HDMI.
Any help would be wonderful.

Comment: I found some answers in these excellent places.

Answer (score 1):

Solutions for the resolution is here 
[Scripts to auto set resolutions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119843/how-to-force-multiple-monitors-correct-resolutions-for-lightdm) 
and here
[Xrandr ArchWiki usage](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xrandr)
The code allows you to add and set a custom resolution for the specified monitor.