# How to disable clone display mode on Ubuntu login screen?

Tags: display, clone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to force Multiple Monitors correct resolutions for LightDM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119843/how-to-force-multiple-monitors-correct-resolutions-for-lightdm)

I'm using Toshiba Satellite L750-20C laptop as primary display (screen resolution 1366x768) and AOC e2243Fw monitor as external display (screen resolution 1920x1080).

In most cases laptop lid is closed so external display AOC is dominant. When I power on that configuration, Ubuntu login screen is displayed in clone mode (it is indicative after opening laptop lid and look in both screen displays). In that case both screens are in low resolution mode and login background image is distorted (stretched) on AOC monitor.

Otherwise if I power on laptop display first and then plug AOC monitor in VGA connector, both displays are operating in extended display mode with their native resolution (which is desirable). After closing laptop lid again AOC monitor continues displaying login screen in its native resolution (1920x1080).

Is it possible to disable clone display mode on Ubuntu login screen so each monitor can display login screen in its native resolution?