# Ubuntu Desktop shifted to right

Tags: resolution, display, xrandr

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 (precise) Kernel : 3.5.0-18-generic

I am encountering a strange problem, my whole desktop has shifted to right. This happened after I restored my system, I was getting a blank screen earlier.(something is better than nothing).

For some reason it also shows my display as laptop.[image]

**Running xrandr**

> xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for
> output default Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 1024 x 768,
> maximum 1024 x 768 default connected 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
> 1024x768        0.0*     800x600         0.0      640x480         0.0

**Running lspci**

> lspci -nn | grep VGA
>
> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd
> Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
> [8086:0102] (rev 09)
> My Display on window supports maximum of 1366*768.
> I do not want to reinstall everything please help.

It is  cycled around as mentioned by  Eliah Kagan
For correcting my blank screen issue I edited my grub file I edited this line and added nomodeset, without it screen gets all [grained](http://image.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/779173/119251378/stock-photo-television-screen-with-static-noise-caused-by-bad-signal-reception-119251378.jpg) up.

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset "

When I boot from live CD also I get the same shifted screen

**Update 2**

Tried booting from live CD with 11.04 same issue

**Update 3**
.xsession-errors file : http://pastebin.com/uveSgNa8

**Update 4**

> xrandr -q | grep -w connected
>
> xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
>
> default connected 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm

Comment: It looks like the display is *cycled around*: panel applets that usually appear on the very right side of the top panel are on the left instead (in the [full-size screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/d6fOK.jpg)). When you move your mouse pointer to the right, past the right edge of the screen, does it appear on the left? Also, what did you do to restore your system from the black screen problem (and do you have any information about what caused that)? This seems like [a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) but if you **edit your question** with more info we may know for sure.

Comment: We need to know what kind of graphics hardware you have in this machine.  Can you include the output of `lspci -nn | grep VGA` in your question?

Comment: Added the information, is there any other anything else I should add

Comment: Looks like the background is the right size, did you try using the monitor buttons to try to re-center the screen?

Comment: I tried that, it shifts entire screen but to no good

Comment: I really don't know about solving this, but if you get the same problem booting from a live CD/other distributions, did you consider that this might be a hardware problem? Do you have a dualboot? If so, do you have the same pb with the other OSs?

Comment: I tried a different monitor, same issue. The system has only ubuntu :)

Comment: This seems a very weird bug within the hardware or a critical bug in the driver/controller...

Comment: Can you add the output of the file: .xsession-errors herein? This should be in your /home directory as a hidden (the '.' character) file. THat should provide us with some diagnostic information.

Comment: added the file, please see update 3

Comment: Is the problem solved by now?

Comment: No I am using it like this, trying few things in between. I was thinking may be some mother board issue, have to check this.

Comment: This happens with the 13.04 live system? If it does then either is a bug or some bad piece of hardware.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 (precise) , yea I also think now it is because of the hardware still using it in the same state

Comment: Look for resolution settings. Often they are not properly set and result in shifting of the desktop. I had the same problem on my tft screen, but adjusting the monitor resolution to proper settings did the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is resolved I was searching for why I was getting

> Failed to get size of gamma for output default Screen

on running **xrandr**. I came across this post

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1594308&page=2#16

and followed the steps mentioned there

> The correct solution would be to set up an xorg.conf file with your
>   resolution;could be done by Xorg -configure (little pain,because it
>   includes the whole bunch of possible configuration options);so it
>   might be worth to try an existing xorg.conf file from the web. Found
>   this xorg.conf e.g. :

This was an interesting issue My desktop is normal now thanks to all who helped out.

Answer (score 5):

Did you try pressing "Auto Set" button on your monitor??
I once experienced the same problem.
But i got it solved just by pressing "Auto" button on my monitor...

Answer (score 1):

Was your problem solved? If not...
I see from your xsession-errors that the issue is in the [EDID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_display_identification_data) file from your monitor:
"unable to get EDID for output"

**FIRST SHOT**

I had that when I tried to connect an external monitor from its VGA in to the HDMI port of my laptop using a VGA-to-HDMI conversor. It caused the problem.
Then I switched to the DVI-D in of the external monitor and used a DVI-to-HDMI conversor. That solved my problem with the EDID thing. Maybe because the both signals were digital now... I don't know.

After that I had to do some tweaking on the screen's resolution (Ubuntu 12.04) as shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119843/how-to-force-multiple-monitors-correct-resolutions-for-lightdm).

**SECOND SHOT**

Try deleting the /home/$USERNAME/.config/monitors.xml file.

Type:

```
$ rm ~/.config/monitors.xml
```

That's a long guess for your problem, but who knows. Don't worry, this file is rebuild every time you save your Display Preferences.

**THIRD SHOT**

Type:

```
$ xrandr -q | grep -w connected
```

It shows which display is in use (e.g. LVDS1 or VGA1).

Then you can type:

```
$ xrandr --output LVDS1 --primary --auto
```

Note that you should change "LVDS1" to the according display in use.

Hope it works!

Comment: I can't try yours and @Diogenes solutions until this coming Tuesday :|. I will update as soon as possible

Comment: OK. Good luck! If my THIRD SHOT worked, you can make it permanent using the answer I've posted [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/360645/intel-gma-x3100-external-monitor-resolution-issue/369841#369841).

Comment: added third's results to question's update 4, second does not work and first is yet to be tried. I will update.

Answer (score 0):

Installing a proprietary video card driver might help by allowing you to move the area of the screen. At least the nvidia x-server settings app would allow you to do that if you have an nvidia card. Not sure about the AMD catalyst, though.

Comment: He uses intel, IMO there is no Inter proprietary drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have higher resolution settings available? If so try and set it to the highest settings you have... ↓

[image]

Comment: Its set at highest resolution  setting that is 1024x768

Answer (score 0):

I have a NVIDIA card and I went into the DASH> NVIDIA X Server Settings > X Server Display Configuration.

Then I set the default video input 1920x1080 (for me) and change the ViewPortOut to 1768x992+80+40. That lets me have my resolution but not screw anything up, when my Ubuntu bugged out to scroll the desktop when I moused to the bottom or the right of my screen this had changed and was my problem.

Sorry if it doesn't appy.

///EDIT: Sorry to modify this value click the "Advanced" Button on the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Check the vbios of your computer by restarting and entering bios. Check video display and reset, adjust.

Printout the vbios if you have questions.

Did you say you tried to adjust the screen in in the front controlls?

Comment: where can I find vbios settings in bios ??

Comment: F9 or F10 during bootup.