# Dual Monitor Problem xrandr

Tags: xrandr, mint, fluxbox

Using `fluxbox` with Linux Mint.

I have this script to set dual screen in fluxbox

```
xrandr --output DP-1 --off --output DVI-I-1 --mode 1600x900 --pos 1440x0 --rotate normal --output DVI-D-1 --mode 1440x900 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --output HDMI-1 --off
```

However my Login screen is not extended

Is there anyway I can set this script to run when the OS start?

Or (if possible)  Boot linux without any desktop manager, start X and initialize fluxbox in command line.

Comment: this appears to be what you are looking for http://askubuntu.com/questions/119843/how-to-force-multiple-monitors-correct-resolutions-for-lightdm . Also, to drop to text CTRL+ALT+F2, to stop lightdm: `sudo service lightdm stop` and to start X after stopping lightdm: `startx`

Comment: That is possible, but how can I ignore lightdm? Boot linux without any desktop manager, start X and initialize fluxbox in command line.

Comment: Plus that workaround doesn't work for me. File ~/.config/monitors.xml doesn't exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```
sudo apt-get purge lightdm
```

and before you accept the changes make sure it is not also going to remove any applications you want to keep or need to use in the process.

Do the same for gdm or gdm3 and any other dm(s) that may still be installed; I've never done it but it should boot to one of the tty screens if no dm is present.

Use the command,

```
startx
```

after you login.

dbus should already be started, however, if it's not, you won't be able to start X without it. To start dbus use:

```
sudo service dbus start
```