# How do I get HDMI out working with Bumblebee?

Tags: 12.04, hdmi, nvidia-optimus

This is a repost of a questions i posted in another question thread that contained other questions.  [previous quetion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134107/ubuntu-12-04-bumblebee-hdmi-and-others)I just pulled this out of that question.

System: Asus N43J Intel i5 2.53GHz Nvidia GeForce GT425m VRAM1GB Dual Boot Win7 & Ubuntu 12.04

I can't get the HDMI to work. I've read all kinds of posts, websites, suggestions for about 2 weeks now, ever since 12.04 came out. I can't find anything that works.

I'm using Bumblebee, following the wiki and several other websites, including this: askubuntu how well.... Bumblebee appears to be working when i use the optirun glxspheres or . However, the hdmi isn't working. When i plug it into the TV, nothing happens (like the desktop showing up on the TV). But, when i run, say "optirun totem", the screen goes black, like it is trying, but nothing is being transmitted. When i take out the cable, the little screensaver on the TV comes back.

I saw this video: [Bumblebee NVidia Optimus hdmi support on KDE](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z1zkKan91i8). He's using the (apparently) exact laptop I'm using. All seems to be working.

Any help here?

I can't get HDMI to work.  Bumblebee seems to be doing fine, as i can optirun *program* just fine, and when i optirun VLC/totem, the above happens.

Comment: Perhaps http://wiki.bumblebee-project.org/Multi-monitor-setup contains some pointers that can help you? Perhaps you need to change ConnectedMonitor. The default is DFP, use http://bumblebee-project.org/issues/21 to check whether your monitor is detected. As mentioned in the wiki, remove the UseEDID line. All changes refer to /etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia

Comment: @Lekensteyn I have the same problem and the tips in the link you posted partially fixed it. I used the procedure in the section "extra screen". One issue - there is no audio over the HDMI. I think this is probably a separate issue though.

Answer (score 1):

I had (and solved) a similar problem.

I've just installed fresh Ubuntu 12.04 with bumblebee 3.0 and when i try to test it using for example "optirun firefox" i get a blank screen with only the mouse cursor.

When I switch to another console (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> for example) and coming back to the regular console (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>) I see that the firefox window has been opened.

I did

```
sudo apt-get purge bumblebee
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-current
```

and then installed the bumblebee again

```
sudo apt-get install bumblebee
```

and it started working properly.

Answer (score 0):

See my post here [HDMI Issues with Optimus solved](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117717/acer-aspire-8951g-nvidia-optimus-and-hdmi-issues-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelot)
It is likely that you have a similar problem and that your TV/monitor and its resolutions are not being identified correctly.