# Nvidia optimus hdmi out tutorial not working correctly

Tags: 12.04, hdmi, nvidia-optimus, lxde

After recently installing **ubuntu 12.04 Desktop Edition** lts on my nvida optimus equipped laptop (ASUS N53J) I tried to get hdmi out to work by using the method described in this guide [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/08/get-hdmi-working-with-nvidia-optimus-on.html). I am able to move my mouse off screen but the LXDE session does not show up on my external monitor. I have tried it with 2 diffrent monitors and many reboots with no success. I have installed bumblebee successfully and both the nvidia graphics card and the intel integrated graphics run well on the laptop monitor.

Here is a paste of the terminal that I started the session from. Note: Retry in 1 second message repeats forever.

```
linux-user@Marble:~$ sudo ~/hdmi
[sudo] password for linux-user: 
Obt-Message: Xinerama extension is not present on the server
xscreensaver: 10:51:29: locking is disabled (running as nobody).
xscreensaver: 10:51:29: locking only works when xscreensaver is launched
 by a normal, non-privileged user (e.g., not "root".)
 See the manual for details.

(polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1:2189): polkit-gnome-1-WARNING **: Unable to determine the session we are in: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.GeneralError: Unable to lookup session information for process '2189'
Openbox-Message: Requested key "XF86Terminal" does not exist on the display

** (update-notifier:2206): WARNING **: not starting for system user

Home directory /home/linux-user not ours.
Connection failure: Connection refused
pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused
** Message: applet now removed from the notification area

** (nm-applet:2199): WARNING **: Failed to register as an agent: (32) No session found for uid 0
** Message: using fallback from indicator to GtkStatusIcon
** Message: applet now embedded in the notification area
2013-04-06T10:51:32 INFO: Synergy 1.3.8 Server on Linux 3.5.0-26-generic #42~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Mar 11 22:17:58 UTC 2013 x86_64
/build/buildd/synergy-1.3.8/src/cmd/synergys/synergys.cpp,1098
2013-04-06T10:51:32 DEBUG: opening configuration "/root/.synergy.conf"
/build/buildd/synergy-1.3.8/src/cmd/synergys/synergys.cpp,1113
2013-04-06T10:51:32 DEBUG: cannot open configuration "/root/.synergy.conf"
/build/buildd/synergy-1.3.8/src/cmd/synergys/synergys.cpp,1120
2013-04-06T10:51:32 DEBUG: opening configuration "/etc/synergy.conf"
/build/buildd/synergy-1.3.8/src/cmd/synergys/synergys.cpp,1113
2013-04-06T10:51:32 DEBUG: cannot open configuration "/etc/synergy.conf"
/build/buildd/synergy-1.3.8/src/cmd/synergys/synergys.cpp,1120
synergys: no configuration available
** Message: Starting applet secret agent because GNOME Shell disappeared

** (nm-applet:2199): WARNING **: Failed to register as an agent: (32) No session found for uid 0
2013-04-06T10:51:37 INFO: Synergy 1.3.8 Client on Linux 3.5.0-26-generic #42~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Mar 11 22:17:58 UTC 2013 x86_64
/build/buildd/synergy-1.3.8/src/cmd/synergyc/synergyc.cpp,765
2013-04-06T10:51:37 DEBUG: XOpenDisplay(":8")
/build/buildd/synergy-1.3.8/src/lib/platform/CXWindowsScreen.cpp,901
2013-04-06T10:51:37 DEBUG: xscreensaver window: 0x01600001
/build/buildd/synergy-1.3.8/src/lib/platform/CXWindowsScreenSaver.cpp,342
2013-04-06T10:51:37 DEBUG: screen shape: 0,0 640x480 
/build/buildd/synergy-1.3.8/src/lib/platform/CXWindowsScreen.cpp,136
2013-04-06T10:51:37 DEBUG: window is 0x00e00004
/build/buildd/synergy-1.3.8/src/lib/platform/CXWindowsScreen.cpp,137
2013-04-06T10:51:37 DEBUG: opened display
/build/buildd/synergy-1.3.8/src/lib/synergy/CScreen.cpp,41
2013-04-06T10:51:37 NOTE: started client
/build/buildd/synergy-1.3.8/src/cmd/synergyc/synergyc.cpp,339
2013-04-06T10:51:37 NOTE: connecting to '127.0.0.1': 127.0.0.1:24800
/build/buildd/synergy-1.3.8/src/lib/client/CClient.cpp,115
2013-04-06T10:51:37 WARNING: failed to connect to server: Connection refused
/build/buildd/synergy-1.3.8/src/cmd/synergyc/synergyc.cpp,274
2013-04-06T10:51:37 DEBUG: retry in 1 seconds
/build/buildd/synergy-1.3.8/src/cmd/synergyc/synergyc.cpp,246
2013-04-06T10:51:38 NOTE: connecting to '127.0.0.1': 127.0.0.1:24800
/build/buildd/synergy-1.3.8/src/lib/client/CClient.cpp,115
2013-04-06T10:51:38 WARNING: failed to connect to server: Connection refused
/build/buildd/synergy-1.3.8/src/cmd/synergyc/synergyc.cpp,274
2013-04-06T10:51:38 DEBUG: retry in 1 seconds
/build/buildd/synergy-1.3.8/src/cmd/synergyc/synergyc.cpp,246
2013-04-06T10:51:39 NOTE: connecting to '127.0.0.1': 127.0.0.1:24800
/build/buildd/synergy-1.3.8/src/lib/client/CClient.cpp,115
2013-04-06T10:51:39 WARNING: failed to connect to server: Connection refused
/build/buildd/synergy-1.3.8/src/cmd/synergyc/synergyc.cpp,274
2013-04-06T10:51:39 DEBUG: retry in 1 seconds
/build/buildd/synergy-1.3.8/src/cmd/synergyc/synergyc.cpp,246
2013-04-06T10:51:40 NOTE: connecting to '127.0.0.1': 127.0.0.1:24800
/build/buildd/synergy-1.3.8/src/lib/client/CClient.cpp,115
2013-04-06T10:51:40 WARNING: failed to connect to server: Connection refused
/build/buildd/synergy-1.3.8/src/cmd/synergyc/synergyc.cpp,274
2013-04-06T10:51:40 DEBUG: retry in 1 seconds
/build/buildd/synergy-1.3.8/src/cmd/synergyc/synergyc.cpp,246
2013-04-06T10:51:42 NOTE: connecting to '127.0.0.1': 127.0.0.1:24800
/build/buildd/synergy-1.3.8/src/lib/client/CClient.cpp,115
2013-04-06T10:51:42 WARNING: failed to connect to server: Connection refused
/build/buildd/synergy-1.3.8/src/cmd/synergyc/synergyc.cpp,274
2013-04-06T10:51:42 DEBUG: retry in 1 seconds
/build/buildd/synergy-1.3.8/src/cmd/synergyc/synergyc.cpp,246
linux-user@Marble:~$ 2013-04-06T10:51:43 NOTE: connecting to '127.0.0.1': 127.0.0.1:24800
```

I think that something has gone wrong in starting up the LXDE session (I see a lot of failed messages) so I'm hoping that you guys can help. If you need any more details about the system or how I installed it I will be happy to give them.

Thanks for any ideas on how this could be fixed.=)

Output of

```
uname -r
```

this (top line is the command)

```
linux-user@Marble:~$ uname -r
3.5.0-27-generic
```

Output of

```
lspci -v
```

this (top line is the command)

```
linux-user@Marble:~$ lspci -v
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 18)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1117
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: agpgart-intel

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor PCI Express x16 Root Port (rev 18) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
I/O behind bridge: 0000d000-0000dfff
Memory behind bridge: c0000000-d30fffff
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: pcieport
Kernel modules: shpchp

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 18) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1532
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 49
Memory at d3400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
I/O ports at e080 [size=8]
Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel modules: i915

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1117
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 47
Memory at d9c0a000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: mei
Kernel modules: mei

00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1117
Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
Memory at d9c08000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 06)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1113
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 48
Memory at d9c00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
I/O behind bridge: 0000c000-0000cfff
Memory behind bridge: d8800000-d9bfffff
Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000d3100000-00000000d32fffff
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: pcieport
Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
I/O behind bridge: 0000b000-0000bfff
Memory behind bridge: d7400000-d87fffff
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: pcieport
Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=0
I/O behind bridge: 0000a000-0000afff
Memory behind bridge: d6000000-d73fffff
Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000d9d00000-00000000d9efffff
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: pcieport
Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
Bus: primary=00, secondary=05, subordinate=05, sec-latency=0
I/O behind bridge: 00009000-00009fff
Memory behind bridge: d4c00000-d5ffffff
Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000d9f00000-00000000da0fffff
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: pcieport
Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
Bus: primary=00, secondary=06, subordinate=06, sec-latency=0
I/O behind bridge: 00008000-00008fff
Memory behind bridge: d3800000-d4bfffff
Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000da100000-00000000da2fffff
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: pcieport
Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1117
Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
Memory at d9c07000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd

00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a6) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
Bus: primary=00, secondary=07, subordinate=07, sec-latency=32
Capabilities: <access denied>

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 06)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1117
Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel modules: lpc_ich

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1117
Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 46
I/O ports at e070 [size=8]
I/O ports at e060 [size=4]
I/O ports at e050 [size=8]
I/O ports at e040 [size=4]
I/O ports at e020 [size=32]
Memory at d9c06000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: ahci
Kernel modules: ahci

00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem (rev 06)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1117
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
Memory at d9c04000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: intel ips
Kernel modules: intel_ips

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 [GeForce GT 425M] (rev ff) (prog-if ff)
!!! Unknown header type 7f

03:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
Subsystem: AzureWave AW-NE785 / AW-NE785H 802.11bgn Wireless Full or Half-size Mini PCIe Card
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
Memory at d7400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: ath9k
Kernel modules: ath9k

04:00.0 USB controller: Fresco Logic FL1000G USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 04) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1039
Physical Slot: 3
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
Memory at d6000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR8131 Gigabit Ethernet (rev c0)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1820
Physical Slot: 5
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 50
Memory at d3800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
I/O ports at 8000 [size=128]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: atl1c
Kernel modules: atl1c

ff:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 05)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 8086
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

ff:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 05)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 8086
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

ff:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 05)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 8086
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

ff:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 05)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 8086
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

ff:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 05)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 8086
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

ff:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 05)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 8086
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
```

Comment: This may have been unclear in the question, but I am running Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop Edition 64 bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you actually want to run a new session on the other monitor, or do you just want to be able to run applications (like mplayer) on the other monitor? I wasn't clear from reading your question.

I have an ASUS N56VM and I was able to get mplayer running on the external monitor (connected with HDMI) using bumblebee. Audio doesn't work, unfortunately. I followed the instructions under the heading "extra screen" on this link:

https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Multi-monitor-setup

Here is a copy/paste of the info from that link:

> In order to use an external monitor through the nvidia chip, power
>   management must be disabled for this. Edit
>   /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf and change PmMethod=auto to
>   PmMethod=none (twice).
>
> extra screen
>
> (blob only) In /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf, change
>   KeepUnusedXServer=false to KeepUnusedXServer=true. Remove the UseEDID
>   and Option "AutoAddDevices" "false" lines in
>   /etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia. Trigger a start of the X server with
>   optirun true.
>
> Before running an application on the external monitor, adjust the
>   library path if necessary (or remove it for nouveau) and run:
>
> export DISPLAY=:8
>   LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/nvidia-current:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
>
> Then start your program at your choice (without optirun), it should
>   show up on the external monitor.

And here is the original askubuntu link from which I got this trick. Perhaps it will be helpful for you too.

[How do I get HDMI out working with Bumblebee?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136171/how-do-i-get-hdmi-out-working-with-bumblebee)

Comment: Your solution works.:)

Comment: I managed to get audio working, though I use nvidia-prime instead of bumblebee for hdmi output: [HDMI Audio on Optimus system](http://askubuntu.com/questions/444132/hdmi-audio-on-optimus-system/511907#511907). Though, a similar solution might work for bumblebee as well.