# Ubuntu HDMI audio not working Ubuntu - S/PDIF unmuted

Tags: 16.04

I have read a number of threads but they all point me to the same conclusion - one that doesn't work for me. This conclusion is to ensure that S/PDIF is unmuted and that HDMI / Digital Audio is available. Well I confirm this but still no audio.

So I can't get HDMI audio out via with Ubuntu.

I've tried switching the audio using the command line via **pactl** as well as the PulseAudio Volume Control GUI and the Ubuntu Sound Control applet but no go. When I switch to digital the audio from the laptop speaker turns off and then there is a complete silence.

I can confirm that **Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output** is listed in PulseAudio Volume Control and when I query **pacmd** I get:

```
    input:analog-stereo: Analogue Stereo Input (priority 60, available: unknown)
    output:analog-stereo: Analogue Stereo Output (priority 6000, available: unknown)
    output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analogue Stereo Duplex (priority 6060, available: unknown)
    output:analog-surround-21: Analogue Surround 2.1 Output (priority 800, available: unknown)
    output:analog-surround-21+input:analog-stereo: Analogue Surround 2.1 Output + Analogue Stereo Input (priority 860, available: unknown)
    output:analog-surround-40: Analogue Surround 4.0 Output (priority 700, available: unknown)
    output:analog-surround-40+input:analog-stereo: Analogue Surround 4.0 Output + Analogue Stereo Input (priority 760, available: unknown)
    output:iec958-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output (priority 5500, available: unknown)
    output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output + Analogue Stereo Input (priority 5560, available: unknown)
    off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
```

So you can see that digital is right there where it should be - **output:iec958-stereo**

This is what I do to switch the audio to digital and analog but HDMI never works:

```
pactl set-card-profile 0 output:iec958-stereo
pactl set-card-profile 0 output:analog-stereo
```

So after I run:

```
pactl set-card-profile 0 output:iec958-stereo
```

all I get is a complete silence. I am not getting any error messages.

So I run **alsamixer** and I confirm that S/PDIF is originally muted **but** pressing the M key unmutes it and the issue still remains - no audio via HDMI.

When I run PulseAudio Volume Control and look at the Playback tab, I can see levels fluctuating indicating that audio is playing except that there is no actual audio output.

What else should I try? My laptop has a dual card configuration, Intel + a discrete nVidia.

**Update - 17/12/2016** I found out why it doesn't work. I am missing the nVidia HDMI Audio option. It appears that something has been mis-configured. Take a look below, no nVidia HDMI Audio option:

```
$ > aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC663 Analog [ALC663 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC663 Digital [ALC663 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

**Update 2 - 17/12/2016** There are some relevant details about this right here: [does not detect my sound card HDMI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/641172/does-not-detect-my-sound-card-hdmi) which I haven't tried yet but in my case, running "sudo lspci -H1" does not list NVIDIA also which makes me conclude that the kernel has not detected the nVidia audio chip.

**Update 3 - 17/12/2016** It appears that this is a bug. Full details: [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1377653)