# HDMI does not stream audio to Monitor/TV 16.04

Tags: 16.04, sound, hdmi

My Computer does not stream audio to external TV connected via HDMI Cable.
I have tried removing pulseaudio, installing pavucontroll etc. 
Here is how It looks like:
[image: AlsaMixer]

[image: PavuInput]

[image: PavuOutput]

[image: Pavu&Sys settings]

Could you please help? The sound seems to be there (the blue bar is moving) yet the TV does not play any of it.

Comment: What is your graphics card? I have AMD Radeon, and needed to define boot parameter `radeon.audio=1` to get audio via HDMI.

Comment: HI, It's GeForce GT 555M

Comment: Regarding your AlsaMixer output, all S/PDIF output channels are muted. Try to unmute them (see ftp://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/gpu-hdmi-audio-document/gpu-hdmi-audio.html#_ensure_all_hdmi_outputs_are_unmuted)

Comment: Sorry, I did not realize on first glance that the AlsaMixer screen shows the configuration of the builtin Intel audio. Find your HDMI card # by issuing `aplay -l` and then run `alsamixer -c card#` to see if HDMI is muted...

Comment: Tried to unmute: http://imgur.com/hkPyEA4, did not help. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: You unmuted the S/PDIF of the builtin Intel Audio (see my last comment). When in AlsaMixer, hit `F6` and select the HDMI output.

Comment: Hmm.. There is no HDMI output in alsa mixer as in the snapshot: http://imgur.com/a/jKYfx I have tried to enter name 'HDMI 0' with no luck, also on some sound test it responds the device is busy: http://imgur.com/a/YG6FY

Comment: So your graphics card HDMI output is not recognized. I can't help any further; maybe [this older post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/641172/does-not-detect-my-sound-card-hdmi/) may help.

Comment: Have you tried another HDMI cable?

Comment: Nope, will try, Could this be it? in the meantime I have tried to reinstall Nvidia drivers and change to Nouveau drivers with no luck, currently switched from 364 (propertiary) to  375.26 (same issue)